# ScrollView not working in Windows 10

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-10, uwp

I have a ViewModel with about 200 contacts and I am binding it to a ListView

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer         
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListView x:Name="ContactListing" ItemsSource="{Binding ContactListing}"  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
                        <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail,Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=contactConv}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Would be great if someone could explain the details behind the ScrollViewers visibility

Comment: You need to give the scrollviewer a height and width

Comment: But how do I  change based on window size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ListView` control already contains a `ScrollViewer` and implements scrolling based on the amount of items, there is no need to wrap this control in another `ScrollViewer`. You can double check this in the default ControlTemplate of `ListView` at line 6219 in the generic.xaml file containing all Windows 10 styles:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.10240.0\Generic\generic.xaml

So you simply have to remove the `ScrollViewer` from your XAML fragment.

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="ContactListing" ItemsSource="{Binding ContactListing}"  >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
                    <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail,Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=contactConv}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

*Note: As you're using a `ListView`, I suppose you want all your items stacked above each other. If you want multiple columns to show your items, use a `GridView` instead.*

Comment: Thanks. This works in a simple page but if I put SplitView content I get the same issue. The ScrollViewer doesn't show up. I would like the ScrollViewer to come up based on the windows size

Comment: Is there a control in your visual tree between the SplitView's content and the Grid in your code snippet that prevents using the full screen size?

Comment: You sure it isn't there? Because default scrollview behaviour is that it will only be visible during scrolling. It will fade out again after scrolling.

Comment: Bart : No there isn't. I've put in a Grid in the SplitView.Content and the ListView in the grid.

Depechie: Am sure. The list view seems to think it has space and expands of screen.

Comment: Bart was right I had the splitview in a grid with height as AUTO. as soon as I changed it * it worked